# Use of units of measurement

Tags: uso-de-palabras

*Entre 50 y 60 ml* or *Entre 50 ml y 60 ml*?

I have seen the former more than the latter in written and spoken Spanish, but I wanted to be sure.

Couldn't find anything on the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Para evitar la repetición de sonidos similares, es preferible usar `50 y 60 ml`. Es lo mismo que hacemos con el sufijo `mente` cuando usamos varios adverbios

> Lo explicó clara y rápidamente  <sub>(y no, "lo explicó **claramente** y **rápidamente**")</sub>

Aparte, si la conjunción es disyuntiva

> Poner 1 ó 2 cucharadas de azúcar

se sigue la misma regla, y se solía acentuar la "o", para que quede claro que es "1 ó 2  = una **o** dos" y no parezca "1o2 = 102 = ciento dos". Ahora parece ser que [puede dejarse sin acentuar](http://www.rae.es/consultas/la-conjuncion-o-siempre-sin-tilde-incluso-entre-cifras).

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Me hace sentido. Ahora, ¿hay alguna fuente en que esté documentado esto o alguna otra regla de la que se pueda derivar esta explicación?